# Trace-to-plane capacitance?

Tags: pcb, capacitance

I'm routing some traces which carry high speed UART at 1.8432 Mbaud. The traces will be routed on the same layer as a power or ground plane (because it's a 2-layer design.) This will introduce capacitance.

My questions are:

- How much capacitance on average will a 6 mil trace with 6 mil spacing on each edge have? If there isn't a general rule, is there a way to calculate it?
- How much capacitance is too much capacitance?

Comment: This is not a data rate that is likely to cause you difficulty for moderately intelligent routing within typically sized PCBs, especially if you series terminate with a resistor at the driving pin.  But this is a data rate that is is starting to get into the territory where cabling between boards or devices may need impedance-matched termination (probably resistive) to prevent reflections from causing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating the capacitance between two tracks edge to edge is not so easy, because it's not the parallel plate scenario so it's all fringing fields. [This calculator](http://chemandy.com/calculators/rectangular-capacitor-calculator.htm) is for tracks over planes, with fringing taken into account. The same site has an inductance calculator which you should also take into account. Obviously both will depend on the length of track.

In terms of how much is too much, it will be clear when your pulses start to show a rounding effect which alter the received width of the pulses. So it depends on the tolerance of the receiver, at what point does it fail to receieve the signal correctly? You end up with a budget: the receiver tolerance has to allow for transmitter tolerance plus the transmission distortions.

In the end, you probably have to prototype it to find out, because it's not just the PCB track-ground capacitance that could affect the signal, there is capacitance between IC pins.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here 
http://www.eeweb.com/electronics-quiz/calculate-the-capacitance-of-pcb-planes (as you have wrire-to-wire cap, area will be much much lower).

Capacitance will be <1pF per inch, so at 2 Mbaud I wouldn't bother about capacitance.
But there are also inductance and EM interference. Anyway, under 10Mhz it is not a deadly problem worth simulating.

Your maximum tolerable capacitance depend on your drive strength. At 1.8 Mboud at some 50 pF you should be fine I believe on most of the chips.

Just check signal quality after assembling first board to be sure that it's ok. And if you have any motors, relays e.t.c in your device - you will have to shield your trace.

Comment: people regularly use the clock rate as the measure of their signal speed. It is not, you need to use the knee frequency which is related to the rise time.

Comment: The 'knee frequency' you refer to, would that also be known as the 'edge rate'?